# Pull Failed, Rebase Failed, stashing doesn't help in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, rebase, pull, line-endings

When I am trying to pull from repository, it says

```
        13:42   Git Pull Failed
        Your local changes would be overwritten by merge.
        Commit, stash or revert them to proceed. View them
```

When I am trying to rebase, it says

```
        13:47   Rebase Failed
        Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
        Retry.
        Note that some local changes were stashed before rebase.
```

Stashing doesn't help (after stash finishes, the situation is the same).

If I open the list of changes, files, diff reports, that content is identical except line separators.

How to get out of this dead end?

Comment: I speculate that your IntelliJ is auto saving your files with line endings other than the original line endings of one or more of your files.  Fix the line ending problem.

Comment: Does [that](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) help? I Never dared to change anything as i only had minor issues.